# Create Dynamic form from json in android

Tags: java, android

I am new in android development. I am making one application like student registration so in that I want to create form dynamically from `JSON` file. and that forms are in the wizard like view. I have no idea that how to do this dynamically please help me to create this.

I have following JSON file :

```
{
    "screen1": {
    "Basic Information" :[
        {
            "id": "3",
            "type": "birthdate",
            "ordering": "2",
            "name": "Birthdate",
            "tips": "Enter your date of birth so other users can know when to wish you happy birthday ",
            "options": "",
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "textarea",
            "ordering": "3",
            "name": "About me",
            "tips": "Tell us more about yourself",
            "options": "",
        },
        {
            "id": "16",
            "type": "select",
            "ordering": "4",
            "name": "marital status",
            "tips": "single or married",
            "options": [
                "Married",
                "Unmarried",
                "Divorcee"
            ],

        }
    ]
},

    "screen3":
    {
     "Education" :[
        {
            "id": "14",
            "type": "text",
            "name": "College / University",
            "tips": "Your college or university name",
            "options": "",
        },
        {
            "id": "15",
            "type": "text",
            "ordering": "16",
            "name": "Graduation Year",
            "tips": "Graduation year",
            "options": "",
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: i want to make dynamic form based on this json file

Answer (score 0):

sorry for long answer:
 try:

> "screen1": -> "\"screen1\" "  +":"
>   like this, only change " to " \" "